# Find number of binary numbers with certain constraints

Tags: algorithm

This is more of a puzzle than a coding problem. I need to find how many binary numbers can be generated satisfying certain constraints. The inputs are

```
(integer) Len - Number of digits in the binary number
(integer) x
(integer) y
```

The binary number has to be such that taking any x adjacent digits from the binary number should contain at least y 1's.

For example -

> Len = 6, x = 3, y = 2
>
> 0 1 1 0 1 1 - Length is 6, Take any 3 adjacent digits from this and
>   there will be 2 l's

I had this C# coding question posed to me in an interview and I cannot figure out any algorithm to solve this. Not looking for code (although it's welcome), any sort of help, pointers are appreciated

Comment: `011011` has a length of 6 or 5? If you want to create an algorithm for your problem you need to clear out if, let's say, `000101` is a valid number found by the algorithm, which is actually `101` (less than `111111`, the biggest number considering the `Len` variable) and it also satisfies the `(x,y)` condition. Basically, you have to know if you are looking in the `000000` - `111111` interval or just `100000` - `111111`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici 000101 is not a valid number, "any x adjacent digits from the binary number should contain at least y 1's", and 000 doesn't.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi, `101` is smaller than the biggest number generated by the `Len = 6` variable (i.e. `111111`). Should the algorithm count only between numbers that have a binary representation of exactly 6 digits or between all the numbers that are smaller or equal than `111111`? If the latter, `Len` will be only 3 for `101`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I think you should consider the entire sequence and not its decimal representation. It's a sequence of bit. Maybe the question could be "How many binary numbers of Length=Len can be generated..."

Comment: What's the length of generated numbers? Should be = Len or <= Len? It's not clear.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi =Len

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example of LEN = 6, X = 3 and Y = 2...

Build an exhaustive bit pattern generator for X bits. A simple binary counter can do this. For example, if X = 3
then a counter from 0 to 7 will generate all possible bit patterns of length 3.

The patterns are:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Verify the adjacency requirement as the patterns are built. Reject any patterns that do not qualify.
Basically this boils down to rejecting any pattern containing fewer than 2 '1' bits (Y = 2). The list prunes down to:

```
011
101
110
111
```

For each member of the pruned list, add a '1' bit and retest the first X bits. Keep the new pattern if it passes the
adjacency test. Do the same with a '0' bit. For example this step proceeds as:

```
1011  <== Keep
1101  <== Keep
1110  <== Keep
1111  <== Keep
0011  <== Reject
0101  <== Reject
0110  <== Keep
0111  <== Keep
```

Which leaves:

```
1011
1101
1110
1111
0110
0111
```

Now repeat this process until the pruned set is empty or the member lengths become LEN bits long. In the end
the only patterns left are:

```
111011
111101
111110
111111
110110
110111
101101
101110
101111
011011
011101
011110
011111
```

Count them up and you are done.

Note that you only need to test the first X bits on each iteration because all the subsequent patterns were verified in prior steps.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, you must have at LEAST y bits not EXACTLY y bits

Comment: @Patashu fixed to accept/reject patterns based on having at least Y bits set.

Comment: This is along the lines of the solution I had given but if Length=10 then it takes way too much time.

Comment: @Arun Length is less of a problem than the difference between X and Y. When Y = 0 the answer set contains 2^Len patterns because all bit patterns count (doesn't matter what X is at this point). When Y = X only 1 pattern containing all '1' bits is in the answer set. Solutions where Y is large relative to X are quickly found because of the "prune as you go strategy", but get exponentially slower/larger as Y decreases relative to X. So this algorithm has an O(2^Len) worst case space and time requirement but gets much better as Y increases relative to X.

Comment: oops I meant Length=100 and x=10, because then you would have generated a certain number of binary numbers with 10 digits and then you would have to loop thru all of them until you reach 100 digits (Adding 90 more 0's or/and 1's), and it takes too much time

Comment: @Arun Agreed. This is a fundamental problem with any generate and test algorithm where certain inputs
lead to exponential set sizes. Just enumerating the possible solutions where Len = 100, X = 10
and Y << X would be problematic, likely running into the trillions. The only reasonable approach
under these conditions is a direct mathematical solution as was attempted in the answer by Mikeb.

Comment: Well for lack of a better solution I have marked this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved using dynamic programming. The main idea is to group the binary numbers according to the last x-1 bits and the length of each binary number. If appending a bit sequence to one number yields a number satisfying the constraint, then appending the same bit sequence to any number in the same group results in a number satisfying the constraint also.

For example, x = 4, y = 2. both of 01011 and 10011 have the same last 3 bits (011). Appending a 0 to each of them, resulting 010110 and 100110, both satisfy the constraint.

Here is pseudo code:

```
mask = (1<<(x-1)) - 1
count[0][0] = 1
for(i = 0; i < Len-1; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 1<<i && j < 1<<(x-1); ++j) {
        if(i<x-1 || count1Bit(j*2+1)>=y)
            count[i+1][(j*2+1)&mask] += count[i][j];
        if(i<x-1 || count1Bit(j*2)>=y)
            count[i+1][(j*2)&mask] += count[i][j];
    }
}
answer = 0
for(j = 0; j < 1<<i && j < 1<<(x-1); ++j)
    answer += count[Len][j];
```

This algorithm assumes that Len >= x. The time complexity is O(Len*2^x).

**EDIT**

The `count1Bit(j)` function counts the number of 1 in the binary representation of `j`.

The only input to this algorithm are `Len, x, and y`. It starts from an empty binary string `[length 0, group 0]`, and iteratively tries to append 0 and 1 until length equals to Len. It also does the grouping and counting the number of binary strings satisfying the 1-bits constraint in each group. The output of this algorithm is `answer`, which is the number of binary strings (numbers) satisfying the constraints.

For a binary string in group `[length i, group j]`, appending 0 to it results in a binary string in group `[length i+1, group (j*2)%(2^(x-1))]`; appending 1 to it results in a binary string in group `[length i+1, group (j*2+1)%(2^(x-1))]`.

Let `count[i,j]` be the number of binary strings in group `[length i, group j]` satisfying the 1-bits constraint. If there are at least `y` 1 in the binary representation of `j*2`, then appending 0 to each of these `count[i,j]` binary strings yields a binary string in group  `[length i+1, group (j*2)%(2^(x-1))]` which also satisfies the 1-bit constraint. Therefore, we can add `count[i,j]` into `count[i+1,(j*2)%(2^(x-1))]`. The case of appending 1 is similar.

The condition `i<x-1` in the above algorithm is to keep the binary strings growing when length is less than x-1.

Comment: Your solution requires a set of binary numbers as input, whereas the requirement is to count or to generate and then count binary numbers satisfying the criteria

Comment: @Arun No, the input to this algorithm is Len, x, and y only. Edited for more explanation about the algorithm.

Comment: @CS.Ferng So the complexity of the algorithm is exponential with respect to y?

Comment: @ElKamina The complexity is exponential with respect to x. y is only a threshold and does not affect the complexity.

Comment: I think I need to be a maths genius to understand this solution. I'm trying to code this to verify the output but I'm stuck in the second last line "for(j = 0; j < 1<<i && j < 1<<(x-1); ++j)" What is i's value ?

Comment: @Arun i is the index of the outer for-loop, which means the length of binary string considered in this iteration. If a binary string has only i bits, its group number (last x-1 bits, or all i bits if i<x-1) cannot be greater than 2^i. That's why "j < 1<<i".

Comment: Can you please provide an implementation of your algo in the language that you see fit... Like @Arun I tried to code it (in C, just copy paste and adding some `;`) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that input values are variable and wanted to see the actual output, I used recursive algorithm to determine all combinations of 0 and 1 for a given length :

```
    private static void BinaryNumberWithOnes(int n, int dump, int ones, string s = "")
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            if (BinaryWithoutDumpCountContainsnumberOfOnes(s, dump,ones))
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            return;
        }
        BinaryNumberWithOnes(n - 1, dump, ones, s + "0");
        BinaryNumberWithOnes(n - 1, dump, ones, s + "1");
    }
```

and *BinaryWithoutDumpCountContainsnumberOfOnes* to determine if the binary number meets the criteria

```
private static bool BinaryWithoutDumpCountContainsnumberOfOnes(string binaryNumber, int dump, int ones)
    {
        int current = 0;
        int count = binaryNumber.Length;
        while(current +dump < count)
        {
            var fail = binaryNumber.Remove(current, dump).Replace("0", "").Length < ones;
            if (fail)
            {
                return false;
            }
            current++;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Calling BinaryNumberWithOnes(6, 3, 2) will output all binary numbers that match

```
010011
011011
011111
100011
100101
100111
101011
101101
101111
110011
110101
110110
110111
111011
111101
111110
111111
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be a tree-recursive algorithm.

Our recursive method would slowly build the number up, e.g. it would start at `xxxxxx`, return the sum of a call with `1xxxxx` and `0xxxxx`, which themselves will return the sum of a call with `10`, `11` and `00`, `01`, etc. except if the x/y conditions are NOT satisfied for the string it would build by calling itself it does NOT go down that path, and if you are at a terminal condition (built a number of the correct length) you return 1. (note that since we're building the string up from left to right, you don't have to check x/y for the entire string, just also considering the newly added digit!)

By returning a sum over all calls then all of the returned 1s will pool together and be returned by the initial call, equalling the number of constructed strings.

No idea what the big O notation for time complexity is for this one, it could be as bad as `O(2^n)*O(checking x/y conditions)` but it will prune lots of branches off the tree in most cases.

**UPDATE:** One insight I had is that all branches of the recursive tree can be 'merged' if they have identical last `x` digits so far, because then the same checks would be applied to all digits hereafter so you may as well double them up and save a lot of work. This now requires building the tree explicitly instead of implicitly via recursive calls, and maybe some kind of hashing scheme to detect when branches have identical `x` endings, but for large length it would provide a huge speedup.

Comment: It's a long time approach. And the question is "How many number can be generated satisfying this condition?". With your algorithm for Len = 200 your answer will take years.

Comment: @Francesco De Lisi Yeah, it does feel very slow, but the question doesn't say 'How would I write an algorithm that solves it with time complexity O(blah) or better' so I just wrote one that's easy to prove works :)

Comment: @Francesco De Lisi I thought of one possible speedup, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I think the bit choice has some reason. Maybe the number of y occurences in x ancient bits of a L sequence has a kind of formula (permutation? Max/Min distance between elements?). I'll update when I find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a nested for loop would do the trick. Pseudocode (not tested).

```
value = '0101010111110101010111'   // change this line to format you would need
for (i = 0; i < (Len-x); i++) {    // loop over value from left to right
     kount = 0
     for (j = i; j < (i+x); j++) { // count '1' bits in the next 'x' bits
         kount += value[j]         // add 0 or 1
         if kount >= y then return success
     }
}
return fail
```

Comment: This code checks that one instance of a binary number of length `Len` satisfy the condition. The problem is to find how many such numbers exists. Do you really think you can try the `2^Len` numbers ?

Comment: I misinterpreted the problem, so I changed my pseudocode. Since Len is a signed integer, there are only about 4 Billion values to check if integer is 32 bits (I guess negative numbers are valid also.) To optimize, I would think about look-up tables.

Answer (score 0):

So in a series of Len binary digits, you are looking for a x-long segment that contains y 1's ..

See the execution: http://ideone.com/xuaWaK

Here's my Algorithm in Java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static ArrayList<String> solve (String input, int x, int y)
    {
        int s = 0;
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        String segment = null;

        for (int i=0; i<(input.length()-x); i++)
        {
            s = 0;
            segment = input.substring(i,(i+x));

            System.out.print(" i: "+i+" ");

            for (char c : segment.toCharArray())
            {
                System.out.print("*");

                if (c == '1')
                {
                    s = s + 1;
                }
            }

            if (s == y)
            {
                matches.add(segment);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        return matches;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String input = "011010101001101110110110101010111011010101000110010";

        int x = 6;

        int y = 4;

        ArrayList<String> matches = null;

        matches = solve (input, x, y);

        for (String match : matches)
        {
            System.out.println(" > "+match);
        }

        System.out.println(" Number of matches is " + matches.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, he's not looking for a single x-long segment, but rather _each_ x-long segment in a Len-long binary digit must contain y ones.

Comment: yes, I am looking for the number of such Binary numbers that can be generated that satisfy the criteria, not to validate if a given number satisfies the condition

Comment: @Arun check the link I provided, see the execution

Comment: I'm not saying your code is wrong, You have misunderstood my question, I'm looking for a count of binary numbers of a certain length satisfying my criteria

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: I checked the link, and only a few of the reported matches are actually matches.

Comment: @Arun use matches.size() to get the count

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to start by getting the all binary numbers with the minimum number of 1's, which is easy enough, you just get every unique permutation of a binary number of length x with y 1's, and cycle each unique permutation "Len" times. By flipping the 0 bits of these seeds in every combination possible, we are guaranteed to iterate over all of the binary numbers that fit the criteria.

```
from itertools import permutations, cycle, combinations

def uniq(x):
    d = {}
    for i in x:
        d[i]=1
    return d.keys()


def findn( l, x, y ):
    window = []
    for i in xrange(y):
        window.append(1)
    for i in xrange(x-y):
        window.append(0)

    perms = uniq(permutations(window))
    seeds=[]
    for p in perms:
        pr = cycle(p)
        seeds.append([ pr.next() for i in xrange(l) ]) ###a seed is a binary number fitting the criteria with minimum 1 bits

    bin_numbers=[]
    for seed in seeds:
        if seed in bin_numbers: continue
        indexes = [ i for i, x in enumerate(seed) if x == 0] ### get indexes of 0 "bits"
        exit = False
        for i in xrange(len(indexes)+1):
            if( exit ): break
            for combo in combinations(indexes, i): ### combinatorically flipping the zero bits in the seed
                new_num = seed[:]
                for index in combo: new_num[index]+=1
                if new_num in bin_numbers:
                    ### if our new binary number has been seen before
                    ### we can break out since we are doing a depth first traversal
                    exit=True
                    break
                else:
                    bin_numbers.append(new_num)

    print len(bin_numbers)

findn(6,3,2)
```

Growth of this approach is definitely exponential, but I thought I'd share my approach in case it helps someone else get to a lower complexity solution...

Answer (score 0):

Set some condition and introduce simple help variable.

```
L = 6, x = 3 , y = 2 introduce d = x - y = 1
```

**Condition**: if the list of the next number hypotetical value and the previous x - 1 elements values has a number of 0-digits > d next number concrete value must be 1, otherwise add two brances with both 1 and 0 as concrete value.

*Start: check(Condition) => both 0,1 due to number of total zeros in the 0-count check.*

```
Empty => add 0 and 1
```

Step 1:Check(Condition)

```
0 (number of next value if 0 and previous x - 1 zeros > d(=1)) -> add 1 to sequence
1 -> add both 0,1 in two different branches
```

Step 2: check(Condition)

```
01 -> add 1

10 -> add 1
11 -> add 0,1 in two different branches
```

Step 3:

```
011 -> add 0,1 in two branches

101 -> add 1 (the next value if 0 and prev x-1 seq would be 010, so we prune and set only 1)

110 -> add 1
111 -> add 0,1
```

Step 4:

```
0110 -> obviously 1
0111 -> both 0,1

1011 -> both 0,1

1101 -> 1
1110 -> 1
1111 -> 0,1
```

Step 5:

```
01101 -> 1
01110 -> 1
01111 -> 0,1

10110 -> 1
10111 -> 0,1

11011 -> 0,1
11101 -> 1
11110 -> 1
11111 -> 0,1
```

Step 6 (Finish):

```
011011 
011101 
011110
011111

101101 
101110 
101111

110110
110111

111011 
111101 
111110
111111
```

Now count. I've tested for L = 6, x = 4 and y = 2 too, but consider to check the algorithm for special cases and extended cases.

**Note**: I'm pretty sure some algorithm with Disposition Theory bases should be a really massive improvement of my algorithm.

Comment: This is similar to the answer posted by Neal but less efficient since it starts with 1 digit and proceeds from there whereas there we start with x digits

Comment: @Arun the difference is about the sequence generation. Here we test at first, then generate. In Neal answer he generates then test then prune. This is like a look ahead, maybe we can build a better solution from this starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The number of patterns of length X that contain at least Y 1 bits is countable. For the case `x == y` we know there is exactly one pattern of the `2^x` possible patterns that meets the criteria. For smaller `y` we need to sum up the number of patterns which have excess `1` bits and the number of patterns that have exactly `y` bits.

```
 choose(n, k) = n! / k! (n - k)!

 numPatterns(x, y) {
     total = 0
     for (int j  = x;  j >= y; j--)
        total += choose(x, j)
     return total
 }
```

For example :

```
X = 4, Y = 4 : 1 pattern
X = 4, Y = 3 : 1 + 4 = 5 patterns
X = 4, Y = 2 : 1 + 4 + 6 = 11 patterns
X = 4, Y = 1 : 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 = 15 patterns
X = 4, Y = 0 : 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 16 
  (all possible patterns have at least 0 1 bits)
```

So let `M` be the number of `X` length patterns that meet the `Y` criteria. Now, that `X` length pattern is a subset of `N` bits. There are `(N - x + 1)` "window" positions for the sub pattern, and `2^N` total patterns possible. If we start with any of our `M` patterns, we know that appending a `1` to the right and shifting to the next window will result in one of our known `M` patterns. The question is, how many of the `M` patterns can we add a `0` to, shift right, and still have a valid pattern in `M`?

Since we are adding a zero, we have to be either shifting away from a zero, or we have to already be in an `M` where we have an excess of `1` bits. To flip that around, we can ask how many of the `M` patterns have exactly `Y` bits and start with a `1`. Which is the same as "how many patterns of length `X-1` have `Y-1` bits", which we know how to answer:

```
shiftablePatternCount = M - choose(X-1, Y-1)
```

So starting with M possibilities, we are going to increase by `shiftablePatternCount` when we slide to the right. All patterns in the new window are in the set of `M`, with some patterns now duplicated. We are going to shift a number of times to fill up `N` by `(N - X)`, each time increasing the count by `shiftablePatternCount`, so the full answer should be :

```
totalCountOfMatchingPatterns = M + (N - X)*shiftablePatternCount
```

- edit - realized a mistake. I need to count the duplicates of the shiftable patterns that are generated. I think that's doable. (draft still)

Answer (score 0):

- I  am not sure about my answer but here is my view.just take a look at it,
- Len=4,
- x=3,
- y=2.
- i just took out two patterns,cause pattern must contain at least y's 1.
- X 1 1 X
- 1 X 1 X
- X - represent don't care
- now count for 1st expression is 2 1 1 2 =4
- and for 2nd expression 1 2 1 2 =4
- but 2 pattern is common between both so minus 2..so there will be total 6 pair which satisfy the condition.

Comment: So your solution requires generating the patterns first ? That is the problem because it'll take too much time to generate all the patterns. And what's the logic behind substituting the X for 2's and the -2 at the end ?

Also 1 x 1 x does not satisfy the condition since taking the last 3 digits, there are no 2 1's

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be using a algoritem similar to your problem, trying to find a way to improve it, I found your question. So I will share

```
static int GetCount(int length, int oneBits){
int result = 0;
double count = Math.Pow(2, length);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
    {
        string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(length, '0');
        if (str.ToCharArray().Count(c => c == '1') == oneBits)
        {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

not very efficent I think, but elegent solution.